# Create new T, X and populate class using reflections C#

Tags: c#

Little background:

- I am reading data from a text file
- File has header row and then any number of item rows
- Could have multiple header/items sections
- I have a mapping (xml) created and loaded into an object which details 1)position 2)required 3)data type 4)class property name to populate this into (Header/Item)

My Solution

Since we have files with different mappings, i have gone the generic function route to read the file and build the corresponding object to be used by the processor later.

The approach is working as you can see from the image below. But I don't think I am handling `new()` properly/optimally for both T and X, especially handling of X in `FillItems`. Any suggestions regarding how i can make this better?

[image]

Model classes to hold data

```
public class Header
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Read File Utility (excluding file read part for simplicity)

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static List<T> LoadData<T, X>() where T: new()
    {
        List<T> headers = new List<T>();

        //using relections to read file and fill
        PropertyInfo[] myMainProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var head = new T();
        foreach (var p in myMainProperties)
        {
            switch (p.Name)
            {
                case "Id":
                    p.SetValue(head, "1");
                    break;
                case "Description":
                    p.SetValue(head, "Some thing");
                    break;
                case "Items":
                    var items = FillItems<X>();
                    p.SetValue(head, items);
                    break;
            }
        }

        headers.Add(head);

        return headers;
    }

    //cant use where X: new(), on FillItems call above rueults in an error => get X should be non abstract type
    private static List<X> FillItems<X>() 
    {
        List<X> items = new List<X>();

        PropertyInfo[] myItemsProperties = typeof(X).GetProperties();

        //is there a better way to handle this. 
        X item = default(X);
        item = Activator.CreateInstance<X>();

        foreach (var p in myItemsProperties)
        {
            switch (p.Name)
            {
                case "Id":
                    p.SetValue(item, "1");
                    break;
                case "Description":
                    p.SetValue(item, "Item Some thing");
                    break;
            }
        }

        items.Add(item);

        return items;
    } 

}
```

and finally the calling part

```
var myMain = Utility.LoadData<Header, Item>();
```

My confusion is with regard to use of `new()` for both T and X. Just want to make sure that i am not missing a better approach here.

Comment: LoadData needs to constrain X as well as T: `public static List<T> LoadData<T, X>() where T : new() where X : new()`. Then you can constrain X on FillItems(): `private static List<X> FillItems<X>() where X : new()`. It will compile. I don't want to think about whether it works. When a generic class or method has to resort to reflection to do anything useful with the objects, you're doing generics wrong. The classes should have virtual methods that do what's needed. You can add a further constraint that they have to implement an interface or inherit from a base class.

Comment: Constraining X on both methods as @EdPlunkett says should let you use `new`, but even without it, there is no reason to assign `default(X)` to `item` and immediately replace it with a new instance - just do `var item = Activator.CreateInstance<X>();`.

Comment: As @NetMage notes, `default(X)` is just `null` if `X` is a reference type. If you've got the `new()` constraint, `new X()` is fine. And if you don't, `Activator.CreateInstance<X>()` may get you an exception anyway.

Comment: Thanks, i have made the change as per @EdPlunkett noted. Please move your comment as an answer so that i can accept it.